# How do I properly use the select function in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing my first script using BS4 as my intro to web scraping, and I'm having trouble. I'm following along with Automate The Boring Stuff with Python's tutorial where he uses `soup.select('insert class here')` to select classes. When I run the code shown below, it tells me soup is not a proper command `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'select'`

```
import webbrowser
import selenium
import bs4
import requests

table = []

url = 'http://espn.com/mlb/team/stats/_/name/wsh'
r = requests.get(url)
page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
table = soup.select("Table2__th")
print(str(table))
```

Comment: should be `page.select()` not `soup.select()` since you've named your Soup object `page`

Comment: Okay, I fixed that. Now, when I print, it's just giving me an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you actually want data in the table? That content is rendered using javascript so requests alone won't help if you target the table itself.

Better yet would be to grab from script tag then you get all the actual stats. Below I grab that info and put into a tidy dataframe for viewing.

```
import bs4
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://espn.com/mlb/team/stats/_/name/wsh'
r = requests.get(url)
page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'playerStats":(.*),"teamLeaders"' , re.DOTALL)
data = page.find('script', text=r).text
script = r.findall(data)[0]    
players_info = json.loads(script)
player_batting_stats = players_info[0]
expanded_player_batting_stats = players_info[1]

table1 = []
table2 = []
headers = ['Name', 'GP', 'AB', 'R', 'H', '2B', '3B', 'HR', 'RBI', 'TB', 'BB', 'K', 'SB', 'BA', 'OBP', 'SLG', 'OPS', 'WAR']

for player in player_batting_stats:
    name = player['athlete']['name']
    row = [stat['value'] for stat in player['statGroups']['stats']]
    row.insert(0, name)
    table1.append(row)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(table1, columns = headers)
print(df1.head())

# repeat for table2 using expanded_player_batting_stats
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Do you know of any good resources for learning how to work with JS in Python when scraping for data?

Comment: I'm in awe of this technique meant to extract content from script tags.

Comment: @SIM It is so handy. Lucky to have better regex support in python  for sure.

Comment: john - you don't really need to know much js (if any) for this particular approach. Knowing some basic  regex to define the pattern, and json to handle the json object (after parsing from js with json library) are more useful. More generally, knowing some js is very handy for writing your own functionality when web-scraping and needing something not available in python libraries. I've had to do that in other languages but not yet in python as there is so much functionality available for python.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems here:

1. you've defined your soup object as `page`, but then try to refer to it as `soup`. You should be doing `page.select('...')`
2. you're trying to select a specific class in CSS, so your selection should be `".Table2__th"` (in CSS, the class name is preceded by a period). See [Soup Sieve - CSS selector library](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/) for more information about CSS selectors.

Here's a working version of your code:

```
import bs4
import requests

table = []
url = 'http://espn.com/mlb/team/stats/_/name/wsh'
r = requests.get(url)
page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
table = page.select(".Table2__th")
print(str(table))
```

Comment: The examples of CSS-selectors in *Soup Sieve* help to illustrate proper usage in BS4.